# 301 redirect all child pages to parent directory using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I need to 301 redirect all child pages of a specific parent directory on my website.

i.e. redirect `www.example/com/parent/child` and `www.example.com/parent/another-child` etc. to `www.example.com/parent`

Is this achievable using the .htaccess file?

Comment: "parent page" - do you mean "directory"? Is `/parent` a physical directory on the filesystem? If not, how are these URLs being routed?

Comment: I meant directory (edited now) /parent is both a directory and a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site, you can add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(parent/). /$1 [R,L]
```

The `$1` is just a backreference to "parent/" (saves repetition).

Change `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be *permanent*. (But only after you have confirmed that it works.)