# Redirecting all subdirectories of a folder via htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I've searched around and haven't found this specific question asked.

I need to redirect *all* the 'subfolders' of a directory to the parent directory.

For example, the parent directory is `example.tld/directory` and all subdirectories such as `example.tld/directory/subdirectory-1` and e`xample.tld/directory/subdirectory-2` etc all need to redirect to `example.tld/directory`

For clarification, these aren't actual directories but Drupal sub-paths, but I believe it should work to do this via htaccess.

Just to make it crystal clear, the URLs

`example.tld/directory/subdirectory-1`

`example.tld/directory/subdirectory-2`

etc...

should all redirect to

`example.tld/directory`

The idea is to make these subdirectories inaccessible to anyone and be sure that the search engine crawlers do not index these subdirectories.

What would be the proper htaccess code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

After more searching and digging, I did find that this question had been asked, I just didn't know how to word it!

Here's where I found the answer:

[301 redirect all child pages to parent directory using .htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109726/301-redirect-all-child-pages-to-parent-directory-using-htaccess?rq=1)

Here is what the answer is - I tested it and it works perfectly:

> Near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root of your site, you can add the following:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^(parent/). /$1 [R,L]
> ```
>
> The `$1` is just a back-reference to `parent/` (saves repetition).
>
> Change `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent. (But only after you have confirmed that it works.)

Comment: Ha, thought I'd answered something similar before - glad you found it! (Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote other answers you find useful. ;)

Comment: Cool, you've got a great resource here!